# How to write Jasmine Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine

I have some check boxes in my `JSP` page and also same number of 'div' elements.

If the check box is checked corresponding `div` should be visible and remaining `divs should be hidden.

For example if checkbox (`id='first'`) is checked then div (`id='divFirst'`) should be visible and so.

my JQuery code is:

```
$("input[name='category']:checkbox").click(function () {
  var av = document.getElementsByName('category');
  for (var e = 0; e < av.length; e++) {
    var divName = "#div" + av[e].id;
    if (av[e].checked == true) {
      $(divName).show();
    } else {
      $(divName).hide();
    }
  }
}
```

this is my jquery` code which hides/shows division of page depending on check boxes.

But I need to write Jasmine script to test it and  I am new to Jasmine script.
So could any one please tell me how to write Jasmine Script for this to test it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to add the elements into your the body of your test page. This will be done in your `beforeEach` so every test has the same elements. Note that you have to refactor your code cause if you put the script as it is into the test it will try to add the clickHandler before the DOM structure, that will be added in the before block. So just wrapp it into a function that can be called in the `beforeEach` block

```
describe('check box', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    $('body').append('<input name="categoty" type="checkbox"><category id="id1"><div id="divid1"></div></category>')
    //callYourFunction that adds the clickHandler
  })

})
```

Then you have to add the test for every case you wanna test.

```
describe('check box', function () {
  beforeEach(function () {
    $('body').append('<input name="categoty" type="checkbox"><category id="id1"><div id="divid1"></div></category>')
    //callYourFunction that adds the clickHandler
  })

  it('will hide the div when checkbox is checked', function () {
    //trigger the click event
    $('input[name="category"]:checkbox').trigger('click');
    expect($('divid1').css('display')).toEqual('
    none ');
})

})
```